# How to get the date mentioned in the email into the VBA script in Outlook?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have created a rule that executed when outlook receives an mail and it will create the appointment on outlook calendar. In that I need to get the date and time mentioned in the mail as the appointment date.

```vb
Sub NewMeetingRequestFromEmail(email As MailItem)

   Dim app As New Outlook.Application

    Dim meetingRequest As AppointmentItem

    Set meetingRequest = app.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    meetingRequest.Categories = email.Categories
    meetingRequest.Body = email.Body
    meetingRequest.Subject = email.Subject
    meetingRequest.Location = email.Subject
    meetingRequest.Start = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + 1) + #10:00:00 AM#
    meetingRequest.Duration = 60
    meetingRequest.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 45
    meetingRequest.ReminderSet = True

    Dim attachment As attachment
    For Each attachment In email.Attachments
        CopyAttachment attachment, meetingRequest.Attachments
    Next attachment

    Dim recipient As recipient

    Set recipient = meetingRequest.Recipients.Add(email.SenderEmailAddress)
    recipient.Resolve

    For Each recipient In email.Recipients
        RecipientToParticipant recipient, meetingRequest.Recipients
    Next recipient

    Dim inspector As inspector

    Set inspector = meetingRequest.GetInspector

    'inspector.CommandBars.FindControl
    inspector.Display
    meetingRequest.Save

End Sub

Private Sub RecipientToParticipant(recipient As recipient, participants As Recipients)
    Dim participant As recipient

    If LCase(recipient.Address) <> LCase(Session.CurrentUser.Address) Then
        Set participant = participants.Add(recipient.Address)
        Select Case recipient.Type
        Case olBCC:
            participant.Type = olOptional
        Case olCC:
            participant.Type = olOptional
        Case olOriginator:
            participant.Type = olRequired
        Case olTo:
            participant.Type = olRequired
        End Select
        participant.Resolve
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CopyAttachment(source As attachment, destination As Attachments)
    On Error GoTo HandleError

    Dim filename As String

    filename = Environ("temp") & "\" & source.filename

    source.SaveAsFile (filename)

    destination.Add (filename)

    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.